# the trait bound `Uuid: sqlx::Decode<'_, _>` is not satisfied

Tags: rust, actix-web, sqlx

I'm trying to use the UUID data-type for the `club_uid` field in my `Announcement` struct. However, I'm receiving the following error message:

```
the trait bound `Uuid: sqlx::Decode<'_, _>` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `sqlx::Decode<'r, DB>`:
  <bool as sqlx::Decode<'r, sqlx::Any>>
  <bool as sqlx::Decode<'_, Postgres>>
  <i8 as sqlx::Decode<'_, Postgres>>
  <i16 as sqlx::Decode<'r, sqlx::Any>>
  <i16 as sqlx::Decode<'_, Postgres>>
  <i32 as sqlx::Decode<'r, sqlx::Any>>
  <i32 as sqlx::Decode<'_, Postgres>>
  <i64 as sqlx::Decode<'r, sqlx::Any>>
```

Here is the code I wrote:

```rust
use actix_web::{
    get, post,
    web::{Data, Json, Path},
    Responder, HttpResponse
};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize} ;
use sqlx::{self, FromRow};
use uuid::{uuid, Uuid};
use crate::AppState;


#[derive(Serialize, FromRow)]
struct Announcement {
    announcement_uid: String,
    info: String,
    date: String,
    club_uid: Uuid
}

#[post("/announcement")]
pub async fn create_announcement(state: Data<AppState>, body: Json<CreateAnnouncement>) -> impl Responder {
    match sqlx::query_as::<_, Announcement>(
        "INSERT INTO announcement (announcement_uid, info, date, club_uid) VALUES (uuid_generate_v4(), $1, $2, $3) RETURNING announcement_uid, info, date"
    )
        .bind(body.info.to_string())
        .bind(body.date.to_string())
        .bind(Uuid::parse_str(body.club_uid.as_str()))
        .fetch_one(&state.db)
        .await
    {
        Ok(announcement) => HttpResponse::Ok().json(announcement),
        Err(e) => {
            println!("{}", e);
            HttpResponse::InternalServerError().json("Failed to create club announcement")
        }
    }
}
```

I tried manually implementing the mentioned traits but I'm really new to Rust so I don't know how to get around this issue.

Here's my `cargo.toml` for reference:

```
[package]
name = "announcement-api"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
actix = "0.13.3"
actix-web = "4.5.1"
chrono = "0.4.35"
dotenv = "0.15.0"
serde = { version = "1.0.197", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.114"
sqlx = { version = "0.7.4", features = ["runtime-async-std-native-tls", "postgres"] }
uuid = { version = "1.7.0", features = ["v4", "serde"] }
```

Here's the result of `cargo tree` as well:

```
├── actix v0.13.3
│   ├── actix-macros v0.2.4 (proc-macro)
│   │   ├── quote v1.0.35
│   │   │   └── proc-macro2 v1.0.79
│   │   │       └── unicode-ident v1.0.12
│   │   └── syn v2.0.53
│   │       ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.79 (*)
│   │       ├── quote v1.0.35 (*)
│   │       └── unicode-ident v1.0.12
│   ├── actix-rt v2.9.0
│   │   ├── futures-core v0.3.30
│   │   └── tokio v1.36.0
│   │       ├── bytes v1.5.0
│   │       ├── mio v0.8.11
│   │       │   ├── log v0.4.21
│   │       │   │   └── value-bag v1.8.0
│   │       │   └── windows-sys v0.48.0
│   │       │       └── windows-targets v0.48.5
│   │       │           └── windows_x86_64_msvc v0.48.5
│   │       ├── parking_lot v0.12.1
│   │       │   ├── lock_api v0.4.11
│   │       │   │   └── scopeguard v1.2.0
│   │       │   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │       │   │   └── autocfg v1.1.0
│   │       │   └── parking_lot_core v0.9.9
│   │       │       ├── cfg-if v1.0.0
│   │       │       ├── smallvec v1.13.1
│   │       │       └── windows-targets v0.48.5 (*)
│   │       ├── pin-project-lite v0.2.13
│   │       ├── socket2 v0.5.6
│   │       │   └── windows-sys v0.52.0
│   │       │       └── windows-targets v0.52.4
│   │       │           └── windows_x86_64_msvc v0.52.4
│   │       └── windows-sys v0.48.0 (*)
│   ├── actix_derive v0.6.1 (proc-macro)
│   │   ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.79 (*)
│   │   ├── quote v1.0.35 (*)
│   │   └── syn v2.0.53 (*)
│   ├── bitflags v2.4.2
│   ├── bytes v1.5.0
│   ├── crossbeam-channel v0.5.12
│   │   └── crossbeam-utils v0.8.19
│   ├── futures-core v0.3.30
│   ├── futures-sink v0.3.30
│   ├── futures-task v0.3.30
│   ├── futures-util v0.3.30
│   │   ├── futures-core v0.3.30
│   │   ├── futures-io v0.3.30
│   │   ├── futures-sink v0.3.30
│   │   ├── futures-task v0.3.30
│   │   ├── memchr v2.7.1
│   │   ├── pin-project-lite v0.2.13
│   │   ├── pin-utils v0.1.0
│   │   └── slab v0.4.9
│   │       [build-dependencies]
│   │       └── autocfg v1.1.0
│   ├── log v0.4.21 (*)
│   ├── once_cell v1.19.0
│   ├── parking_lot v0.12.1 (*)
│   ├── pin-project-lite v0.2.13
│   ├── smallvec v1.13.1
│   ├── tokio v1.36.0 (*)
│   └── tokio-util v0.7.10
│       ├── bytes v1.5.0
│       ├── futures-core v0.3.30
│       ├── futures-sink v0.3.30
│       ├── pin-project-lite v0.2.13
│       ├── tokio v1.36.0 (*)
│       └── tracing v0.1.40
│           ├── log v0.4.21 (*)
│           ├── pin-project-lite v0.2.13
│           ├── tracing-attributes v0.1.27 (proc-macro)
│           │   ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.79 (*)
│           │   ├── quote v1.0.35 (*)
│           │   └── syn v2.0.53 (*)
│           └── tracing-core v0.1.32
│               └── once_cell v1.19.0
├── actix-web v4.5.1
│   ├── actix-codec v0.5.2
│   │   ├── bitflags v2.4.2
│   │   ├── bytes v1.5.0
│   │   ├── futures-core v0.3.30
│   │   ├── futures-sink v0.3.30
│   │   ├── memchr v2.7.1
│   │   ├── pin-project-lite v0.2.13
│   │   ├── tokio v1.36.0 (*)
│   │   ├── tokio-util v0.7.10 (*)
│   │   └── tracing v0.1.40 (*)
│   ├── actix-http v3.6.0
│   │   ├── actix-codec v0.5.2 (*)
│   │   ├── actix-rt v2.9.0 (*)
│   │   ├── actix-service v2.0.2
│   │   │   ├── futures-core v0.3.30
│   │   │   ├── paste v1.0.14 (proc-macro)
│   │   │   └── pin-project-lite v0.2.13
│   │   ├── actix-utils v3.0.1
│   │   │   ├── local-waker v0.1.4
│   │   │   └── pin-project-lite v0.2.13
│   │   ├── ahash v0.8.11
│   │   │   ├── cfg-if v1.0.0
│   │   │   ├── getrandom v0.2.12
│   │   │   │   └── cfg-if v1.0.0
│   │   │   ├── once_cell v1.19.0
│   │   │   └── zerocopy v0.7.32
│   │   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   │   └── version_check v0.9.4
│   │   ├── base64 v0.21.7
│   │   ├── bitflags v2.4.2
│   │   ├── brotli v3.5.0
│   │   │   ├── alloc-no-stdlib v2.0.4
│   │   │   ├── alloc-stdlib v0.2.2
│   │   │   │   └── alloc-no-stdlib v2.0.4
│   │   │   └── brotli-decompressor v2.5.1
│   │   │       ├── alloc-no-stdlib v2.0.4
│   │   │       └── alloc-stdlib v0.2.2 (*)
│   │   ├── bytes v1.5.0
│   │   ├── bytestring v1.3.1
│   │   │   └── bytes v1.5.0
│   │   ├── derive_more v0.99.17 (proc-macro)
│   │   │   ├── convert_case v0.4.0
│   │   │   ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.79 (*)
│   │   │   ├── quote v1.0.35 (*)
│   │   │   └── syn v1.0.109
│   │   │       ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.79 (*)
│   │   │       ├── quote v1.0.35 (*)
│   │   │       └── unicode-ident v1.0.12
│   │   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   │   └── rustc_version v0.4.0
│   │   │       └── semver v1.0.22
│   │   ├── encoding_rs v0.8.33
│   │   │   └── cfg-if v1.0.0
│   │   ├── flate2 v1.0.28
│   │   │   ├── crc32fast v1.4.0
│   │   │   │   └── cfg-if v1.0.0
│   │   │   └── miniz_oxide v0.7.2
│   │   │       └── adler v1.0.2
│   │   ├── futures-core v0.3.30
│   │   ├── h2 v0.3.25
│   │   │   ├── bytes v1.5.0
│   │   │   ├── fnv v1.0.7
│   │   │   ├── futures-core v0.3.30
│   │   │   ├── futures-sink v0.3.30
│   │   │   ├── futures-util v0.3.30 (*)
│   │   │   ├── http v0.2.12
│   │   │   │   ├── bytes v1.5.0
│   │   │   │   ├── fnv v1.0.7
│   │   │   │   └── itoa v1.0.10
│   │   │   ├── indexmap v2.2.5
│   │   │   │   ├── equivalent v1.0.1
│   │   │   │   └── hashbrown v0.14.3
│   │   │   │       ├── ahash v0.8.11 (*)
│   │   │   │       └── allocator-api2 v0.2.16
│   │   │   ├── slab v0.4.9 (*)
│   │   │   ├── tokio v1.36.0 (*)
│   │   │   ├── tokio-util v0.7.10 (*)
│   │   │   └── tracing v0.1.40 (*)
│   │   ├── http v0.2.12 (*)
│   │   ├── httparse v1.8.0
│   │   ├── httpdate v1.0.3
│   │   ├── itoa v1.0.10
│   │   ├── language-tags v0.3.2
│   │   ├── local-channel v0.1.5
│   │   │   ├── futures-core v0.3.30
│   │   │   ├── futures-sink v0.3.30
│   │   │   └── local-waker v0.1.4
│   │   ├── mime v0.3.17
│   │   ├── percent-encoding v2.3.1
│   │   ├── pin-project-lite v0.2.13
│   │   ├── rand v0.8.5
│   │   │   ├── rand_chacha v0.3.1
│   │   │   │   ├── ppv-lite86 v0.2.17
│   │   │   │   └── rand_core v0.6.4
│   │   │   │       └── getrandom v0.2.12 (*)
│   │   │   └── rand_core v0.6.4 (*)
│   │   ├── sha1 v0.10.6
│   │   │   ├── cfg-if v1.0.0
│   │   │   ├── cpufeatures v0.2.12
│   │   │   └── digest v0.10.7
│   │   │       ├── block-buffer v0.10.4
│   │   │       │   └── generic-array v0.14.7
│   │   │       │       └── typenum v1.17.0
│   │   │       │       [build-dependencies]
│   │   │       │       └── version_check v0.9.4
│   │   │       ├── crypto-common v0.1.6
│   │   │       │   ├── generic-array v0.14.7 (*)
│   │   │       │   └── typenum v1.17.0
│   │   │       └── subtle v2.5.0
│   │   ├── smallvec v1.13.1
│   │   ├── tokio v1.36.0 (*)
│   │   ├── tokio-util v0.7.10 (*)
│   │   ├── tracing v0.1.40 (*)
│   │   └── zstd v0.13.0
│   │       └── zstd-safe v7.0.0
│   │           └── zstd-sys v2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5
│   │               [build-dependencies]
│   │               ├── cc v1.0.90
│   │               │   └── jobserver v0.1.28
│   │               └── pkg-config v0.3.30
│   ├── actix-macros v0.2.4 (proc-macro) (*)
│   ├── actix-router v0.5.2
│   │   ├── bytestring v1.3.1 (*)
│   │   ├── http v0.2.12 (*)
│   │   ├── regex v1.10.3
│   │   │   ├── aho-corasick v1.1.2
│   │   │   │   └── memchr v2.7.1
│   │   │   ├── memchr v2.7.1
│   │   │   ├── regex-automata v0.4.6
│   │   │   │   ├── aho-corasick v1.1.2 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── memchr v2.7.1
│   │   │   │   └── regex-syntax v0.8.2
│   │   │   └── regex-syntax v0.8.2
│   │   ├── serde v1.0.197
│   │   │   └── serde_derive v1.0.197 (proc-macro)
│   │   │       ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.79 (*)
│   │   │       ├── quote v1.0.35 (*)
│   │   │       └── syn v2.0.53 (*)
│   │   └── tracing v0.1.40 (*)
│   ├── actix-rt v2.9.0 (*)
│   ├── actix-server v2.3.0
│   │   ├── actix-rt v2.9.0 (*)
│   │   ├── actix-service v2.0.2 (*)
│   │   ├── actix-utils v3.0.1 (*)
│   │   ├── futures-core v0.3.30
│   │   ├── futures-util v0.3.30 (*)
│   │   ├── mio v0.8.11 (*)
│   │   ├── socket2 v0.5.6 (*)
│   │   ├── tokio v1.36.0 (*)
│   │   └── tracing v0.1.40 (*)
│   ├── actix-service v2.0.2 (*)
│   ├── actix-utils v3.0.1 (*)
│   ├── actix-web-codegen v4.2.2 (proc-macro)
│   │   ├── actix-router v0.5.2 (*)
│   │   ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.79 (*)
│   │   ├── quote v1.0.35 (*)
│   │   └── syn v2.0.53 (*)
│   ├── ahash v0.8.11 (*)
│   ├── bytes v1.5.0
│   ├── bytestring v1.3.1 (*)
│   ├── cfg-if v1.0.0
│   ├── cookie v0.16.2
│   │   ├── percent-encoding v2.3.1
│   │   └── time v0.3.34
│   │       ├── deranged v0.3.11
│   │       │   └── powerfmt v0.2.0
│   │       ├── itoa v1.0.10
│   │       ├── num-conv v0.1.0
│   │       ├── powerfmt v0.2.0
│   │       ├── time-core v0.1.2
│   │       └── time-macros v0.2.17 (proc-macro)
│   │           ├── num-conv v0.1.0
│   │           └── time-core v0.1.2
│   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   └── version_check v0.9.4
│   ├── derive_more v0.99.17 (proc-macro) (*)
│   ├── encoding_rs v0.8.33 (*)
│   ├── futures-core v0.3.30
│   ├── futures-util v0.3.30 (*)
│   ├── itoa v1.0.10
│   ├── language-tags v0.3.2
│   ├── log v0.4.21 (*)
│   ├── mime v0.3.17
│   ├── once_cell v1.19.0
│   ├── pin-project-lite v0.2.13
│   ├── regex v1.10.3 (*)
│   ├── serde v1.0.197 (*)
│   ├── serde_json v1.0.114
│   │   ├── itoa v1.0.10
│   │   ├── ryu v1.0.17
│   │   └── serde v1.0.197 (*)
│   ├── serde_urlencoded v0.7.1
│   │   ├── form_urlencoded v1.2.1
│   │   │   └── percent-encoding v2.3.1
│   │   ├── itoa v1.0.10
│   │   ├── ryu v1.0.17
│   │   └── serde v1.0.197 (*)
│   ├── smallvec v1.13.1
│   ├── socket2 v0.5.6 (*)
│   ├── time v0.3.34 (*)
│   └── url v2.5.0
│       ├── form_urlencoded v1.2.1 (*)
│       ├── idna v0.5.0
│       │   ├── unicode-bidi v0.3.15
│       │   └── unicode-normalization v0.1.23
│       │       └── tinyvec v1.6.0
│       │           └── tinyvec_macros v0.1.1
│       └── percent-encoding v2.3.1
├── chrono v0.4.35
│   ├── num-traits v0.2.18
│   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   └── autocfg v1.1.0
│   └── windows-targets v0.52.4 (*)
├── dotenv v0.15.0
├── serde v1.0.197 (*)
├── serde_json v1.0.114 (*)
├── sqlx v0.7.4
│   ├── sqlx-core v0.7.4
│   │   ├── ahash v0.8.11 (*)
│   │   ├── async-io v1.13.0
│   │   │   ├── async-lock v2.8.0
│   │   │   │   └── event-listener v2.5.3
│   │   │   ├── cfg-if v1.0.0
│   │   │   ├── concurrent-queue v2.4.0
│   │   │   │   └── crossbeam-utils v0.8.19
│   │   │   ├── futures-lite v1.13.0
│   │   │   │   ├── fastrand v1.9.0
│   │   │   │   ├── futures-core v0.3.30
│   │   │   │   ├── futures-io v0.3.30
│   │   │   │   ├── memchr v2.7.1
│   │   │   │   ├── parking v2.2.0
│   │   │   │   ├── pin-project-lite v0.2.13
│   │   │   │   └── waker-fn v1.1.1
│   │   │   ├── log v0.4.21 (*)
│   │   │   ├── parking v2.2.0
│   │   │   ├── polling v2.8.0
│   │   │   │   ├── bitflags v1.3.2
│   │   │   │   ├── cfg-if v1.0.0
│   │   │   │   ├── concurrent-queue v2.4.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── log v0.4.21 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── pin-project-lite v0.2.13
│   │   │   │   └── windows-sys v0.48.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   │   │   └── autocfg v1.1.0
│   │   │   ├── rustix v0.37.27
│   │   │   │   ├── bitflags v1.3.2
│   │   │   │   ├── errno v0.3.8
│   │   │   │   │   └── windows-sys v0.52.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── io-lifetimes v1.0.11
│   │   │   │   │   └── windows-sys v0.48.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   └── windows-sys v0.48.0 (*)
│   │   │   ├── slab v0.4.9 (*)
│   │   │   ├── socket2 v0.4.10
│   │   │   │   └── winapi v0.3.9
│   │   │   └── waker-fn v1.1.1
│   │   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   │   └── autocfg v1.1.0
│   │   ├── async-std v1.12.0
│   │   │   ├── async-channel v1.9.0
│   │   │   │   ├── concurrent-queue v2.4.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── event-listener v2.5.3
│   │   │   │   └── futures-core v0.3.30
│   │   │   ├── async-global-executor v2.4.1
│   │   │   │   ├── async-channel v2.2.0
│   │   │   │   │   ├── concurrent-queue v2.4.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── event-listener v5.2.0
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── concurrent-queue v2.4.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── parking v2.2.0
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── pin-project-lite v0.2.13
│   │   │   │   │   ├── event-listener-strategy v0.5.0
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── event-listener v5.2.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── pin-project-lite v0.2.13
│   │   │   │   │   ├── futures-core v0.3.30
│   │   │   │   │   └── pin-project-lite v0.2.13
│   │   │   │   ├── async-executor v1.8.0
│   │   │   │   │   ├── async-lock v3.3.0
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── event-listener v4.0.3
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├── concurrent-queue v2.4.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├── parking v2.2.0
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   └── pin-project-lite v0.2.13
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── event-listener-strategy v0.4.0
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├── event-listener v4.0.3 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   └── pin-project-lite v0.2.13
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── pin-project-lite v0.2.13
│   │   │   │   │   ├── async-task v4.7.0
│   │   │   │   │   ├── concurrent-queue v2.4.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── fastrand v2.0.1
│   │   │   │   │   ├── futures-lite v2.3.0
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── fastrand v2.0.1
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── futures-core v0.3.30
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── futures-io v0.3.30
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── parking v2.2.0
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── pin-project-lite v0.2.13
│   │   │   │   │   └── slab v0.4.9 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── async-io v2.3.2
│   │   │   │   │   ├── async-lock v3.3.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── cfg-if v1.0.0
│   │   │   │   │   ├── concurrent-queue v2.4.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── futures-io v0.3.30
│   │   │   │   │   ├── futures-lite v2.3.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── parking v2.2.0
│   │   │   │   │   ├── polling v3.5.0
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── cfg-if v1.0.0
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── concurrent-queue v2.4.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── pin-project-lite v0.2.13
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── tracing v0.1.40 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── windows-sys v0.52.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── rustix v0.38.31
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── bitflags v2.4.2
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── errno v0.3.8 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── windows-sys v0.52.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── slab v0.4.9 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── tracing v0.1.40 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   └── windows-sys v0.52.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── async-lock v3.3.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── blocking v1.5.1
│   │   │   │   │   ├── async-channel v2.2.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── async-lock v3.3.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── async-task v4.7.0
│   │   │   │   │   ├── fastrand v2.0.1
│   │   │   │   │   ├── futures-io v0.3.30
│   │   │   │   │   ├── futures-lite v2.3.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── piper v0.2.1
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── atomic-waker v1.1.2
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── fastrand v2.0.1
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── futures-io v0.3.30
│   │   │   │   │   └── tracing v0.1.40 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── futures-lite v2.3.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   └── once_cell v1.19.0
│   │   │   ├── async-io v1.13.0 (*)
│   │   │   ├── async-lock v2.8.0 (*)
│   │   │   ├── crossbeam-utils v0.8.19
│   │   │   ├── futures-core v0.3.30
│   │   │   ├── futures-io v0.3.30
│   │   │   ├── futures-lite v1.13.0 (*)
│   │   │   ├── kv-log-macro v1.0.7
│   │   │   │   └── log v0.4.21 (*)
│   │   │   ├── log v0.4.21 (*)
│   │   │   ├── memchr v2.7.1
│   │   │   ├── once_cell v1.19.0
│   │   │   ├── pin-project-lite v0.2.13
│   │   │   ├── pin-utils v0.1.0
│   │   │   └── slab v0.4.9 (*)
│   │   ├── atoi v2.0.0
│   │   │   └── num-traits v0.2.18 (*)
│   │   ├── byteorder v1.5.0
│   │   ├── bytes v1.5.0
│   │   ├── crc v3.0.1
│   │   │   └── crc-catalog v2.4.0
│   │   ├── crossbeam-queue v0.3.11
│   │   │   └── crossbeam-utils v0.8.19
│   │   ├── either v1.10.0
│   │   │   └── serde v1.0.197 (*)
│   │   ├── event-listener v2.5.3
│   │   ├── futures-channel v0.3.30
│   │   │   ├── futures-core v0.3.30
│   │   │   └── futures-sink v0.3.30
│   │   ├── futures-core v0.3.30
│   │   ├── futures-intrusive v0.5.0
│   │   │   ├── futures-core v0.3.30
│   │   │   ├── lock_api v0.4.11 (*)
│   │   │   └── parking_lot v0.12.1 (*)
│   │   ├── futures-io v0.3.30
│   │   ├── futures-util v0.3.30 (*)
│   │   ├── hashlink v0.8.4
│   │   │   └── hashbrown v0.14.3 (*)
│   │   ├── hex v0.4.3
│   │   ├── indexmap v2.2.5 (*)
│   │   ├── log v0.4.21 (*)
│   │   ├── memchr v2.7.1
│   │   ├── native-tls v0.2.11
│   │   │   └── schannel v0.1.23
│   │   │       └── windows-sys v0.52.0 (*)
│   │   ├── once_cell v1.19.0
│   │   ├── paste v1.0.14 (proc-macro)
│   │   ├── percent-encoding v2.3.1
│   │   ├── serde v1.0.197 (*)
│   │   ├── serde_json v1.0.114 (*)
│   │   ├── sha2 v0.10.8
│   │   │   ├── cfg-if v1.0.0
│   │   │   ├── cpufeatures v0.2.12
│   │   │   └── digest v0.10.7 (*)
│   │   ├── smallvec v1.13.1
│   │   ├── sqlformat v0.2.3
│   │   │   ├── itertools v0.12.1
│   │   │   │   └── either v1.10.0 (*)
│   │   │   ├── nom v7.1.3
│   │   │   │   ├── memchr v2.7.1
│   │   │   │   └── minimal-lexical v0.2.1
│   │   │   └── unicode_categories v0.1.1
│   │   ├── thiserror v1.0.58
│   │   │   └── thiserror-impl v1.0.58 (proc-macro)
│   │   │       ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.79 (*)
│   │   │       ├── quote v1.0.35 (*)
│   │   │       └── syn v2.0.53 (*)
│   │   ├── tracing v0.1.40 (*)
│   │   └── url v2.5.0 (*)
│   ├── sqlx-macros v0.7.4 (proc-macro)
│   │   ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.79 (*)
│   │   ├── quote v1.0.35 (*)
│   │   ├── sqlx-core v0.7.4 (*)
│   │   ├── sqlx-macros-core v0.7.4
│   │   │   ├── async-std v1.12.0 (*)
│   │   │   ├── dotenvy v0.15.7
│   │   │   ├── either v1.10.0 (*)
│   │   │   ├── heck v0.4.1
│   │   │   │   └── unicode-segmentation v1.11.0
│   │   │   ├── hex v0.4.3
│   │   │   ├── once_cell v1.19.0
│   │   │   ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.79 (*)
│   │   │   ├── quote v1.0.35 (*)
│   │   │   ├── serde v1.0.197 (*)
│   │   │   ├── serde_json v1.0.114 (*)
│   │   │   ├── sha2 v0.10.8
│   │   │   │   ├── cfg-if v1.0.0
│   │   │   │   ├── cpufeatures v0.2.12
│   │   │   │   └── digest v0.10.7 (*)
│   │   │   ├── sqlx-core v0.7.4 (*)
│   │   │   ├── sqlx-postgres v0.7.4
│   │   │   │   ├── atoi v2.0.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── base64 v0.21.7
│   │   │   │   ├── bitflags v2.4.2
│   │   │   │   ├── byteorder v1.5.0
│   │   │   │   ├── crc v3.0.1 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── dotenvy v0.15.7
│   │   │   │   ├── etcetera v0.8.0
│   │   │   │   │   ├── cfg-if v1.0.0
│   │   │   │   │   ├── home v0.5.9
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── windows-sys v0.52.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   └── windows-sys v0.48.0
│   │   │   │   │       └── windows-targets v0.48.5 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── futures-channel v0.3.30 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── futures-core v0.3.30
│   │   │   │   ├── futures-io v0.3.30
│   │   │   │   ├── futures-util v0.3.30 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── hex v0.4.3
│   │   │   │   ├── hkdf v0.12.4
│   │   │   │   │   └── hmac v0.12.1
│   │   │   │   │       └── digest v0.10.7 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── hmac v0.12.1 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── home v0.5.9 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── itoa v1.0.10
│   │   │   │   ├── log v0.4.21 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── md-5 v0.10.6
│   │   │   │   │   ├── cfg-if v1.0.0
│   │   │   │   │   └── digest v0.10.7 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── memchr v2.7.1
│   │   │   │   ├── once_cell v1.19.0
│   │   │   │   ├── rand v0.8.5
│   │   │   │   │   ├── rand_chacha v0.3.1 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   └── rand_core v0.6.4 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── serde v1.0.197 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── serde_json v1.0.114 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── sha2 v0.10.8 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── smallvec v1.13.1
│   │   │   │   ├── sqlx-core v0.7.4 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── stringprep v0.1.4
│   │   │   │   │   ├── finl_unicode v1.2.0
│   │   │   │   │   ├── unicode-bidi v0.3.15
│   │   │   │   │   └── unicode-normalization v0.1.23 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── thiserror v1.0.58 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── tracing v0.1.40 (*)
│   │   │   │   └── whoami v1.5.1
│   │   │   ├── syn v1.0.109 (*)
│   │   │   ├── tempfile v3.10.1
│   │   │   │   ├── cfg-if v1.0.0
│   │   │   │   ├── fastrand v2.0.1
│   │   │   │   └── windows-sys v0.52.0 (*)
│   │   │   └── url v2.5.0
│   │   │       ├── form_urlencoded v1.2.1 (*)
│   │   │       ├── idna v0.5.0 (*)
│   │   │       └── percent-encoding v2.3.1
│   │   └── syn v1.0.109 (*)
│   └── sqlx-postgres v0.7.4
│       ├── atoi v2.0.0 (*)
│       ├── base64 v0.21.7
│       ├── bitflags v2.4.2
│       ├── byteorder v1.5.0
│       ├── crc v3.0.1 (*)
│       ├── dotenvy v0.15.7
│       ├── etcetera v0.8.0 (*)
│       ├── futures-channel v0.3.30 (*)
│       ├── futures-core v0.3.30
│       ├── futures-io v0.3.30
│       ├── futures-util v0.3.30 (*)
│       ├── hex v0.4.3
│       ├── hkdf v0.12.4 (*)
│       ├── hmac v0.12.1 (*)
│       ├── home v0.5.9 (*)
│       ├── itoa v1.0.10
│       ├── log v0.4.21 (*)
│       ├── md-5 v0.10.6 (*)
│       ├── memchr v2.7.1
│       ├── once_cell v1.19.0
│       ├── rand v0.8.5 (*)
│       ├── serde v1.0.197 (*)
│       ├── serde_json v1.0.114 (*)
│       ├── sha2 v0.10.8 (*)
│       ├── smallvec v1.13.1
│       ├── sqlx-core v0.7.4 (*)
│       ├── stringprep v0.1.4 (*)
│       ├── thiserror v1.0.58 (*)
│       ├── tracing v0.1.40 (*)
│       └── whoami v1.5.1
└── uuid v1.7.0
    ├── getrandom v0.2.12 (*)
    └── serde v1.0.197 (*)
```

Edit: I needed to add the `uuid` feature of sqlx

Comment: I think either you're missing the `uuid` feature flag, or there is a version mismatch between [`sqlx::types::Uuid`](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/types/struct.Uuid.html) and `uuid::Uuid`, to avoid that just use the reexport in `sqlx`.

Comment: Please post your Cargo.toml and the result of `cargo tree`.

Comment: I just shared it.

Comment: It looks like you've found the answer by yourself. Great! Now, please post a self-answer for posterity.

Comment: I sure will. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Okay so I needed to add the `uuid` feature of `sqlx`. Following that, I had to manually implement the `FromRow` trait by:

```
impl<'r> FromRow<'r, PgRow> for Announcement {
    fn from_row(row: &'r PgRow) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        let announcement_uid: String = row.try_get("announcement_uid")?;
        let info: String = row.try_get("info")?;
        let date: String = row.try_get("date")?;
        let club_uid: Uuid = row.try_get("club_uid")?;

        Ok(Announcement { announcement_uid, info, date, club_uid })
    }
}
```

I hope this helps out anyone with similar issues